# Call a php file from an other php file which has a html form in an echo?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want to delete mysql rows by clicking on a button in a form. The problem is that I do it in a php while cicyle and the html action attribute does not navigate into the other php page, where the code should delete the row. Here's my code:

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<table><tr><th>Vezetéknév</th><th>Keresztnév</th><th>Nemzetiség</th>
 <th>Szülőváros</th><th>Találmányok száma</th></tr>";

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["vezeteknev"]. "</td><td>" . $row["keresztnev"]. 
  "</td><td>" . $row["nemzetiseg"] ."</td><td>" 
     . $row["szulovaros"]. "</td><td>". $row['talalmanyok']. "
     </td> <td><form action='deleterow.php' method='post'>
     <input type='submit' name='delete' value='".$row['id']."'/>
     </form></td></tr>";       
 }
```

The other page (deleterow.php):

```
    header('location:index.php');
    include('DBConnection');

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

    $user  = $_POST['delete'];
    $delet_query = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM feltalalo WHERE id = '$user' ") or die(mysql_error());

 }
```

Comment: And where does `action` navigate to?

Comment: The second code snippet is the deleterow.php where should it navigate to.

Comment: I ask again - if you're not navigated to `deleterow.php` then where are you navigated to?

Comment: And second question - do you know the purpose of `header('location')`?

Comment: You are navigating to deleterow.php but the first command in deleterow.php is to redirect to index.php. After the redirect takes place you are giving commands. No one is there to listen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as like below:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["vezeteknev"]. "</td><td>" . $row["keresztnev"]. 
  "</td><td>" . $row["nemzetiseg"] ."</td><td>" 
     . $row["szulovaros"]. "</td><td>". $row['talalmanyok']. "
     </td> <td><a href='deleterow.php?delete=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td></tr>";       
 }
```

deleterow.php

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){    
    $user  = $_GET['delete'];
    $delet_query = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM feltalalo WHERE id = '$user' ") or die(mysql_error());    
}
```

Comment: So why does moving to `$_GET` should help?

Comment: As you can see requirement to delete single record in loop. so rather then using multiple forms in post method, its better way to use get method

Comment: Also user have to put redirect code after delete. instead of first

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to achieve is to be able to delete an entry using a link, but have it register as a post request.

To achieve this, you need to generate a form just before your link like so

```
<form name="item_deleter_{YOUR_ID}" style="display:none;" method="post" action="{URL_FOR_DELETING}">
 <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="{YOUR_ID}">
</form>
```

Then after this you will create the delete link to have an onclick which submits the above form using javascript like so

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.item_deleter_{YOUR_ID}.submit(); event.returnValue = false; return false;">Delete</a>
```

Cheers